# Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms in Electron and Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

I have an error in Visual Studio Code when I start my Electron app and an alert pops up with a message but the alert disappears after a short time and I can't read the message. Is this alert from Visual Studio Code or Electron?

How do I extend the timeout?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Electron

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can add a timeout option to the launch configuration:

```
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
      {
         "name": "Launch Electron",
         "timeout": 30000...
```

credit @hans-passant